# How to get total number of site visits (Region wise) using Application Insight Analytics in Azure portal?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

I have used below query to get the total number of requests by regions in last 30 days.

```
 requests
| summarize count_=sum(itemCount), avg(duration)
  by bin(timestamp, 1h), client_StateOrProvince, client_City
| order by timestamp asc, client_StateOrProvince, client_City
```

**Here is results**

[image]

But, I am looking for region wise (west us, east us..) , I am not able to find right column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Application Analytics schema does not have a geo-region defined for requests.

In addition to the columns in your summarize statement, you can also add **client_CountryOrRegion** to get the country (although this will give you "United States" and not "West US")